# Inform Open Data Communities for OD stackexchange

Tags: discussion, promotion

Lately, I had several discussions with members from various Open Data communities and I realized that only a few of them are aware for Open Data StackExchange site. I was wondering if there is something we do wrong or there isn't a proper advertisement.

I haven't seen something similar to other meta sites, but I am thinking to create a list with all the possible "clients" of this website and start contacting with them with e-mails and let them know about the website.

Is this something that StackExchange encourage or not?

I will add the list as a wiki answer and please, feel free to update it without asking :)

Answer (score 6):

- [Open Data Innovation](http://theinnovationenterprise.com/)
- [freeourdata.org.uk](http://freeourdata.org.uk)
- [The Open Institute](http://openinstitute.com/)
- [Open Data Institute](http://theodi.org/)
- [Open Knowledge Foundation](http://www.okfn.org)
- [Open Corporates](http://opencorporates.com/)
- [Socrata](http://www.socrata.com/)
- [r/Datasets](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/), [r/OpenData](https://www.reddit.com/r/opendata/)

Comment: a very long list is compiled here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/477/what-are-the-most-common-ways-that-users-find-out-about-new-data-sets/1526#1526

Answer (score 2):

Advertising is definitely needed.

I am very active at Software Recommendations, and there we do a lot of advertising (or rather we did, now the site has become popular and does not need it anymore).

Without advertising we won't attract the people we target.

Comment: Can you share with us what kind of advertising you have done? I am also a member on Software Recommendation but not as much as here.